# HttpContext.User property not working on remote for Identity.Name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, web-applications

So I am making an internal intranet like site and am trying to capture Windows Authentication as the login information for the access of various users to various pages.

In my controller for a page I have:

```
string userId = User.Identity.Name;
```

Which utilises HttpContext.User and when I run this locally, and say my Windows username is `DOMAIN\JoeBlogs` the code successfully manages to capture the `DOMAIN\JoeBlogs` into `userId`.

However, when I deploy it onto one of my DEV servers (still internal) and visit the page, the `userId` is blank, hence `User.Identity.Name` is not capturing the Windows credentials of the user visiting.

Now is this because you can't capture the credentials of a visiting user when that user isn't local to your server? And if so, is it possible at all to capture the Windows username of the user currently browsing the intranet site? (Before anyone says it; security of username spoofing isn't an issue as such, due to the very locked down nature of the machines that users who have access to the intranet are using).

Comment: Have you checked that Windows authentication is enabled on the dev server?

Comment: You'll need to verify that Windows Authentication is on and Basic Authentication is off.